# Suppress the message <IPython.core.display.Javascript object> in Jupyter notebook/lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using python 3.8 with jupyter notebook on a MacPro, OS is Big Sur; following are the details regarding the version;

```
 jupyter core     : 4.6.3
 jupyter-notebook : 6.1.1
 qtconsole        : 4.7.5
 ipython          : 7.17.0
 ipykernel        : 5.3.4
 jupyter client   : 6.1.6
 jupyter lab      : 2.2.4
 nbconvert        : 5.6.1
  ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
  nbformat         : 5.0.7
  traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Whenever I open a jupyter notebook file(.ipynb) then each cell has the output as well as the following message;

```
 <IPython.core.display.Javascript object>
```

Interestingly, when I re-run the cell, the message vanish,s but if I close and reopen the file, the message appears again. For reference purpose, hers is the preamble for my notebook;

```
import nltk

nltk.download("wordnet", quiet=True)
nltk.download("words", quiet=True)
nltk.download("stopwords", quiet=True)
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Can I kindly get help, on how can the message be suppressed for ever? Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall your ipython package

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to solve this permanently, but here's a workaround:

You can try by opening the notebook in any text editor, such as Notepad, and debugging the actual backend code for that specific cell output where that warning is printed.

code will look like this -

```
{
     "data": {
      "application/javascript": [
       "\n",
       "        if (window._pyforest_update_imports_cell) { window._pyforest_update_imports_cell('import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\\nimport numpy as np'); }\n",
       "    "
      ],
      "text/plain": [
       "<IPython.core.display.Javascript object>"
      ]
     },
     "metadata": {},
     "output_type": "display_data"
    }
```

You can see that this warning was generated while importing some libraries in the javascript object here.

```
if (window._pyforest_update_imports_cell) { 
    window._pyforest_update_imports_cell('import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\\nimport numpy as np'); 
}
```

Solution: You can manually import them into your notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the following code

```py
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

or change "all" to "last"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okxZW.png)

[this is the link](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html)

or restart the kernel